# format text input in GtkEntry in C

Tags: c, format, gtk, glade

How can I format text input in GtkEntry in C? I want only numbers in the gtk entry and format it as phone number, like this -> (xx) xxxx-xxxx. I've found it in php but not in C D: I'm using gtk2/glade with C. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess I need to use `changed` signal ?

Comment: if you want to sell the software, don;t do that.

Comment: so what should I do?